# Reading file path from JSON to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

Please, help with this. I generate a JSON string from database, like this

```
<?php
  require_once "pdo.php";

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM locals WHERE article_id = {$_POST['idc']}");
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo(JSON_encode($row['article_image']));
```

And receiving in browser like this

```
$('#local').change(function(event){
    locid = $(this).val();
    $.post('mod/imgtour.php', {'idc':locid}, function(data){
      window.console && console.log(data);
      $.getJSON('mod/artic.php',function(data){
      window.console && console.log(data);
      $('#artimg').attr("src","data.first");
      });
    });
```

But in the console I realize that the data I recieve, which is the path to an image come in this way:  `"images\\locals\\article1.png"`  (the path stored in database is in this form `"images\locals\article1.png"` )

I need the file path comes in the right way, to replace it in the image tag...

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use [`string.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and replace the "\" with "/"?

Comment: I assume the actual data in your table is `images\\locals\\article1.png`. Just replace the slashes in JavaScript. Also, you're wide open to SQL injection. You might want to use parameterised queries to fix that.

Comment: @ObsidianAge the path in the table is store like this 'images\locals\article1.png' but JSON add aditionals '\' Is there a way to eliminate the aditionals '\'?  By the way, I'm no inserting data, just selecting, in this case, how can use parameters in the sql query?

Comment: @Rodrigo, say the the value of idc is " ' '; delete * from locals ", it can potentially delete all the data, it is just an example, there are variations. Also there are performance benefits of using bind variables as then the databases recognize them each request as the same query and does optimizations

Comment: Thanks, all has been valuabe feedback!